んだって + question on と particle
I heard this in a show I was watching
"やばいんだってよ.　三秒以上目が合うと"
"7日後に不幸が来たんだよね”
It was translated something along the lines of "I heard its bad.. if you lock eyes for over 3 seconds".
Is the と here referring to the first sentence? As in the word "If"
=> "If you lock eyes for over three seconds" then やばいんだってよ
is んだってよ のだってよ. Its not clear to me how they inferred the meaning of this sentence as I heard its bad.

The て here is the quotative particle と. Think of it as:
やばいんだと言われている。
This is a very, very common construction in casual speech and writing. It also commonly means 「と思う」. Once you start noticing it, you'll hear it a lot!

so what is the particle　と at the end for? Also for example then can i say 寒いんだってよ meaning "I heard its darn cold" implying someone told me, or i heard somewhere that it was gonna be cold?

@Bing, That's 倒置 (inversion) of 三秒以上目が合うと、やばいんだってよ。 The と is the conditional particle.
